# Improving mount parameters on Proxmox PVE (OpenVZ) server how to

Tags: mount, openvz

We are trying to improve our partitions and mount points while migrating a new (Proxmox PVE 2) server by splitting some partitions in order to improve mount points with specific parameters (as noatime,data=writeback,barrier=0,nobh and others) for web files, mysql, etc
We currently only use OpenVZ containers that share data partitions via bind mounts from the host. This is a data dir is mounted from the hosts /data/xxxx dir. That /data partition has the specific parameters assigned.

I am uncertain if:

- bind mounts on containers inherit whatever mounting specifications of
  this type or need to be reassigned on the VIDXXX.mount file?
- I am aware there is a vzctl param to force it via command line... 
  "vzctl set veid --noatime yes --save" but are there  any other form
  (via conf files) to include the "noatime" or other mount options for
  the VM root itself, or they would be inherited also from the
  /var/lib/vz/ mount options
- are there are any issues as far as PVE itself if the system root
  partition includes params such as noatime?

Answer (score 0):

> [source](http://www.howtoforge.com/openvz-mounting-host-devices-partitions-directories-in-a-container-with-bind-mounts-debian-ubuntu)

If you want to add mount options like noatime, you can add the -o switch to the mount line, e.g. as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
. /etc/vz/vz.conf
. ${VE_CONFFILE}

SRC=/mnt/sdb1
DST=/var/lib/mysql
if [ ! -e ${VE_ROOT}${DST} ]; then mkdir -p ${VE_ROOT}${DST}; fi
mount -o noatime -n -t simfs ${SRC} ${VE_ROOT}${DST} -o ${SRC}
```

Make the script executable...

```
chmod +x /etc/vz/conf/101.mount
```